# Why do my Xamarin TableView rows have different heights?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, tableview

**Repro example**

1. Create a new Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio 2019 (16.5.4).
2. Replace the content of the main page's ContentPage element with the following:

   ```
   <TableView HasUnevenRows="False" RowHeight="50">
       <TableRoot>
           <TableSection Title="MySection">
               <EntryCell Label="Entry Cell 1" />
               <EntryCell Label="Entry Cell 2" />
               <ViewCell>
                   <Label>View Cell 1</Label>
               </ViewCell>
               <ViewCell>
                   <Label>View Cell 2</Label>
               </ViewCell>
           </TableSection>
       </TableRoot>
   </TableView>
   ```
3. Run in your favorite Android emulator.

**Expected result**

All rows in the TableView have the same height. After all, `HasUnevenRows` is `False` and `RowHeight` has been set explicitly.

**Actual result**

The heights differ: The entry cells are significantly higher than the view cells.

[image: Screenshot]

Did I do something wrong or did I find a bug?

Comment: `Entry` and `Label` have different height, this is why your rows have different size, try to use custom renderer for `Entry` and edit the native component height

Comment: @cahyo: If I add an `Entry` in the ViewCell, the problem still persists.

Comment: have you tried specifying a height for each cell?

Comment: @Jason: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.tableview.hasunevenrows?view=xamarin-forms), cell height is ignored if `HasUnevenRows` is `False`.

Comment: @Heinzi By default in xamarin android, `Entry` has bigger height value from `Label`, no metter if you use `EntryCell` (`Label` inside it just placed with horizontal position) or wrapping `Entry` inside `ViewCell` those are rendered with the code and same height value, try to set height value from xaml caused your `Entry` cropped. If you want to make Entry height lower then my suggestion to use custom render or increase Label height to fit with your Entry

Answer (score 1):

I think because **EntryCell** contains a `Label` and `Entry`, it will have a default minimum height, it seems to be greater than 50, you could try to change the `RowHeight` to smaller,such as 20, it will remain the same height, if you set the height greater than his default minimum value, it will be displayed as high as viewcell, you could try to set the height larger, such as 60.

Comment: Yes, increasing the RowHeight fixes that issue. Is it supposed to work that way? The documentation does not mention that RowHeight is a "minimum row height", and setting it to a low value (20) makes the section header too small but not the EntryCell. And I thought `HasUnevenRows` was necessary to get uneven rows?

Comment: @Heinzi yes,Entrycell will use its minimum default if the height is too small.I also didn't find a description of this in the document, but it is logical to have a default minimum height, otherwise the Label and Entry would not be displayed.

Comment: I upvoted it, since it provided a helpful workaround for the issue, but, unfortunately, your explanation is wrong: If you replace `Label` with `Entry` in my MCVE (or with a StackPanel containing both a Label and an Entry), the ViewCell is still smaller than the EntryCell. And if you provide a `MinimumHeightRequest` the Label, it won't fix the issue either, so your theory about the Entry's "default minimum height" does not hold when verified experimentally. Thus, I am still waiting for an answer that consistently explains how this is all supposed to work.

Comment: @Heinzi The default minimum height I'm talking about is not just putting a label and an entry in it, it might have some margin or padding values, I didn't find the appropriate documentation for that, maybe we can wait.

Comment: That's not it either: Adding an insane margin or padding to the ViewCell contents does not change the cell height either. Really strange, I'm more and more inclined to write a bug report for this, but let's see if someone from the XF team finds this question first.

Comment: @Heinzi You could report it to the XF github,you might get a response faster that way.